# Make servo's shaft longer

Tags: motor, servomotor

I’ve got a few servo motors MG995, MG996R, etc.

For my make I need a servo to have a longer shaft – 6cm or so.

I cannot find a way to achieve it.
There is lots of Shaft Coupler for steppers and DC motors in the shop. But they don’t suite a servo motor shaft which is short.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I usually just glue some nylon tubing or something on the servo hub and trim off what I don't want with a rotary tool (or sometimes diagonal cutters when I'm feeling lazy).

Comment: @ScienceGeyser Very interesting. Can you share some photo?

Comment: There are shaft couplers for RC servos also. Google image search for servo shaft coupler returns quite a few variants.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a shopping list queston

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* zhekaus, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I used in a Lego assembly some time back. It's using an FS90 servo which is considerably smaller than the one you list, but You can get the picture. This version of gluing things on, allows some amount of disassembly and reuse. Other glue jobs are not equally as graceful.

To get the servo horn screw in, I had to knock off the corners of the shaft hole in the Lego piece that is glued to the horn. Then the next piece gives good engagement to the shaft.

[image: Assembled Lego servo shaft adapter]
[image: Parts Detail]

Comment: Very nice. But what if I need metallic shaft?

Comment: Well, if you have a machine shop, you use your imagination and machine tools to make yourself the "ideal" coupling. Otherwise, You do as 50k4 suggested and search duckduckgo.com (I don't promote the other search engines).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'd use a bolt or something. I had this issue with the MG995. A 3mm bolt will fit snug into the hole, maybe use some nuts to add spacing?